# How to make Thread wait for a permission check in Splash Screen?

Tags: android

I have a Splash Screen activity, and in this activity I want to get the location permission from the user. However, I couldn't make Thread wait for the permission check before starting activity with intent.
Here is what I have:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean permissionGranted;
    private static final int PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION = 99;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        permissionGranted = false;
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                checkPermission();
            }
        },3000);

        Thread background = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(4000);
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,TutorialPages.class));
                    finish();
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Try again, location permission denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        };

        background.start();


    }
```

And to check Permissions:

```
public void checkPermission(){
        requestPermission();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           // Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashScreen.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Required Location Permission")
                        .setMessage("Location permission is needed to run PassingBuy.")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                        PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION);

            }
        } else {
            // Permission has already been granted
            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            if(location != null){
                                Double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
                                Double altitude = location.getAltitude();


                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this,"GREAT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                permissionGranted = true;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Needed To Run The App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                permissionGranted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void requestPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
```

I tried changing the boolean variable permissionGranted and to put a `while(permissionGranted);` before calling `background.start();` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code (to start the activity) from separate Thread to **onRequestPermissionsResult** method (where the permission is being granted), as follows

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION){
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"GREAT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            permissionGranted = true;

            // Code to start activity
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,TutorialPages.class));
            finish();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Needed To Run The App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            permissionGranted = false;
        }
    }
}
```